# Wifi Dongle not detected in wpagui

Tags: raspbian, wireless, peripherals

I have an edup nano EP-N8508 (listed as a verified periferal in the Raspi wiki). I use it without a hub, directly on Pi. It detects correctly via lsusb and ifconfig. It even shows mac address in ifconfig. But, when I load LXDE and launch wpagui, it does not show up. I am using the latest Raspbian weezy distribution. Any advices? What outputs do I need to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working. The shell script provided in wiki page ( http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals ) was for Squeeze only. I found a script for Wheezy and it works now. The script for Wheezy is here. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80256631/install-wheezy-beta-rtl8188cus-20120619.sh